# Initial proportion of three different patches with only two sliders

Tags: netlogo

i am trying to create a predation model in netlogo with foxes and rabbits. foxes eat rabbits and waste (left from people) und rabbits eat grass in a special pleasure ground. 
the initial proportion of patches fixed in the setup should be: 65% green patches (grass), 35 % brown patches (eaten grass), 10 % margenta patches (waste from people). they can be distributed randomly. 
at the moment it looks like that :

```
globals [grass waste] 
breed [rabbits rabbit]
breed [foxes fox] 
turtles-own [energy] 
patches-own [countdown]


to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor green ]
   if grass? [
    ask patches [
      set pcolor one-of [green brown]
      if-else pcolor = green
      [ set countdown grass-regrowth-time ]
      [ set countdown random grass-regrowth-time ] 
    ]
  ]
  ask patches [ set pcolor magenta ]
    if waste? [
    ask patches [
      set pcolor one-of [ green brown magenta ]
      if-else pcolor = [ green brown ] 
      [ set countdown waste-regeneration-time ]
      [ set countdown random waste-regeneration-time ] 
  ] 
  ]
  set-default-shape rabbits "rabbit"
  create-rabbits initial-number-rabbits 
  [
    set color white
    set size 2.2
    set label-color gray + 1
    set energy random ( 2 * rabbit-gain-from-food)
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  set-default-shape foxes "fox"
  create-foxes initial-number-foxes 
  [
    set color red
    set label-color gray + 1
    set size 2.2
    set energy random ( fox-gain-from-food )
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  display-labels  
  set grass count patches with [pcolor = green]
  set waste count patches with [pcolor = magenta]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Comment: What is your question? Is something not working properly?

Comment: this code is working but i want to implement a initial proportion of green patches, brown patches and magenta patches before starting the modell. and i tried to use "ask n-of ..patches [set pcolor green ]".. but it didn t work! do you have an idee how i could implement the beginning proportion of patches in the "setup"?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include that information. Make sure to include: 1. the exact problem you're trying to fix, 2. the code that didn't work, and 3. *why* it didn't work (whatever error message it gave, or the unexpected result). That will help someone else to understand the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about NetLogo; this came up in a review queue.